# Is it possible to distinguish between locking the device and sending an app to background?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have an app that needs to do something when it’s sent to background using the Home button and something else when the device is locked using the top hardware button. The standard way of solving these requirements are the notifications and delegate methods sent out by `UIApplication`. On iOS 4 they look like this:

```
// Pressing the home button
Will resign active.
Did enter background.
// Tapping app icon on Springboard
Will enter foreground.
Did become active.

// Pressing the lock button
Will resign active.
// Unlocking the device
Did become active.
```

In other words, it’s quite easy to tell between locking and backgrounding. On iOS 5 the behaviour changed:

```
// Pressing the home button
Will resign active.
Did enter background.
// Tapping app icon on Springboard
Will enter foreground.
Did become active.

// Pressing the lock button
Will resign active.
Did enter background.
// Unlocking the device
Will enter foreground.
Did become active.
```

Notice that the `didEnterBackground` and `willEnterForeground` notifications are now sent out even when (un)locking the device, making it impossible to tell between locking and backgrounding. Is this change documented somewhere? Is it a regression? Do you know another way to distinguish the two cases?

Comment: Apple clearly don't want you to distinguish between these events. So if you do find a workaround it might lead to your app being rejected.

Comment: It could not find the issue in the documentation and it used to work differently in iOS 4, so it doesn’t seem as “clear” to me.

Comment: This is how I do it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595928/differentiate-between-screen-lock-and-home-button-press-on-ios7/19771680#19771680

Both work on iOS6 & iOS7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we detect whether a user left through the home button or lock button without listening to darwin notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071009/can-we-detect-whether-a-user-left-through-the-home-button-or-lock-button-without)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### iOS 6

In my preliminary testing via the simulator, checking the application state with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]
```

in either

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

allows you to differentiate between a call to lock the device and just switching back to the homescreen. A lock screen will return 1 (UIApplicationStateInactive), whereas a home button press will register as a 2 (UIApplicationStateBackground).

It seems consistent and should work on an iOS device just as reliably as it does in the simulator.

### iOS 7

The iOS 6 method no longer works in iOS 7. In order to do this now, you have to utilize CFNotificationCenter and listen for a darwin notification (labeled: com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete). You can find the github repo with the sample project here: https://github.com/binarydev/ios-home-vs-lock-button

Credit for the iOS 7 fix goes out to [wqq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889286/wqq)

Comment: Actually, purely from the names of those methods, you shouldn't be able to say with any certainty in `willEnterForeground:` whether the state will return `1` or `2` in different cases, and the state *should* always be `2` in `didEnterBackground:`. I wouldn't rely on this behaviour remaining the same even to the next minor `iOS` version.

Comment: Actually, didEnterBackground is always called as of 5.0, whether you are locking the screen but not leaving the app, or actually leaving the app via the home button. I've tested on the iPad 1 and, and both show the same behavior. This is because when you lock the screen, it will call didEnterBackground, but the UIApplicationStatus will be UIApplicationStateInactive because the app is still in the foreground behind the lock screen. Leaving the app in any way though produces UIApplicationStateBackground like it should. I would not consider this liable to change in any near future version.

Comment: I can confirm this works on both iOS 5 and iOS 6 devices. Thanks!

Comment: @JoseRafaelSantiagoJr. Hi Jose Rafael, I have same problem but this is not working for iOS 7. Is there any way to differentiate these two states in iOS 7.

Comment: @Archive I've confirmed that this has in fact changed in iOS 7. Another stackoverflow user has found a solution, and I've posted a github repo with a sample project showing how to detect this, here:  https://github.com/binarydev/ios-home-vs-lock-button

Comment: @JoseRafaelSantiagoJr. Thanks, thats exactly what i want

Answer (score 7):

I have looked into this quite a bit so I would love to be wrong here if someone knows something I don't, but technically, there is no *documented* way to tell the difference between locking the device, and sending to background.

One thing you can check however, is the `UIApplicationState` during the transition from foreground to background.  Locking a device will give `UIApplicationStateInactive` and moving the App to the background will give `UIApplicationStateBackground`.  But, since this behaviour is not officially documented it may change in the future.

A basic example:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
    NSLog(@"Device state: %@", state);
    switch (state) {
        case UIApplicationStateActive:
            /* ... */
            break;
        case UIApplicationStateInactive:
            /* Device was/is locked  */
            break;
        case UIApplicationStateBackground:
            /* User pressed home button or opened another App (from an alert/email/etc) */
            break;
    }
}
```

---

> `UIApplicationState` - The running states of an application
>
> ```
> typedef enum {
>     UIApplicationStateActive,   
>     UIApplicationStateInactive,
>     UIApplicationStateBackground
> }
> ```
>
> `UIApplicationState`
>
> **Constants**
>   `UIApplicationStateActive` - The application
>   is running in the foreground and currently receiving events. Available
>   in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> `UIApplicationStateInactive` -  The application is running in the
>   foreground but is not receiving events. This might happen as a result
>   of an interruption or because the application is transitioning to or
>   from the background.
>
> `UIApplicationStateBackground` - The application is
>   running in the background.

---

According to the [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

```
applicationWillResignActive:
didEnterBackground:
// ...
willEnterForeground:
applicationDidBecomeActive:
```

are the only methods that ever get called in both situations.

---

According to the [iOS 4.3 to iOS 5.0 API Diff](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html), these are the ONLY changes regarding `UIApplication` or `UIApplicationDelegate`, so I couldn't find where they documented any of these notification changes:

```
UIApplication.h
Added -[UIApplication setNewsstandIconImage:]
Added UIApplication.userInterfaceLayoutDirection
Added UIApplicationDelegate.window
Added UIApplication(UINewsstand)
Added UIApplicationLaunchOptionsNewsstandDownloadsKey
Added UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability
Added UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection
Added UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionLeftToRight
Added UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft
```

Comment: Just an FYI - this behavior has changed in iOS 8 + Swift. Locking the device while the app is in the foreground now uses `UIApplicationStateBackground`

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a workaround/hack, but according to my experience it's very reliable.
When the device is screen-locked (not just home button-ed, if that's a word :)) - *bound* network (UDP) sockets are broken.
I was using GCDAsyncUDPSocket (also AsyncUDPSocket before) and they both fire a network/broken pipe error reliably when the device is turned off.
In my case I need the UDP socket anyway, for other apps it might be a bit smelly, however, just binding/listening on a UDP socket without any action is not too terrible if you really need to differentiate here.

This note will [self destruct]; is 5 minutes (so Apple won't find out).

Answer (score 1):

There’s a [thread about this issue on Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/119433) (registered developers only, sorry). The gist is that the new behaviour is by design. There are requests for a new API feature to distinguish between the two use cases, but nothing working yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what Apple's iOS Programming Guide says:

> Pressing the Sleep/Wake button is another type of interruption that
>   causes your app to be deactivated temporarily. When the user presses
>   this button, the system disables touch events, moves the app to the
>   background but sets the value of the app’s applicationState property
>   to UIApplicationStateInactive (as opposed to
>   UIApplicationStateBackground), and finally locks the screen.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

So, you should check the `UIApplication`'s `applicationState` property in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`. If it is `UIApplicationStateBackground` the user pressed the home button. But if it is `UIApplicationStateInactive` the user locked the device.

Comment: FWIW, in my testing on iOS 7 this does not appear to be true.  In fact, I never see a value of UIApplicationStateInactive anywhere.