# Differentiate between screen lock and home button press on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiapplication

I need to do something in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. But I need to differentiate which user action causes the "enter background": screen lock or home button press.

I was using this code, which is from this [post - How to differentiate between screen lock and home button press on iOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9893656):

```
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    NSLog(@"Sent to background by locking screen");
} else if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    NSLog(@"Sent to background by home button/switching to other app");
}
```

It works fine on iOS6. but on iOS7 (both device and simulator), I always get `UIApplicationStateBackground`, whether the user clicks the home or the lock button.

Does someone have an idea about what could cause this? iOS 7 updates to multi-task background handling? Or some setting of my app (my app's background mode is off)?

And is there an alternative solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to differentiate between screen lock and home button press on iOS5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303703/how-to-differentiate-between-screen-lock-and-home-button-press-on-ios5)

Comment: I think I didn't state it clearly enough. I read the post on your link but that doesn't work any more in iOS7. I don't think it's a duplicate . But anyway, I edit my question to make it clear.

Comment: Good idea to clarify, plus the edit bumps your post back to the top so others see it again. :D

Comment: @Perisheroy I also have the same problem. Did you find any solution for that problem? If found please help me.

Answer (score 19):

This can help you both on iOS6 & iOS7 :).

When user press lock button you will get a `com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete` notification.

```
//new way
//put this in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                    NULL,
                                    displayStatusChanged,
                                    CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete"),
                                    NULL,
                                    CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);

//put this function in AppDelegate
static void displayStatusChanged(CFNotificationCenterRef center,
                                 void *observer,
                                 CFStringRef name,
                                 const void *object,
                                 CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {
    if (name == CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete")) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"kDisplayStatusLocked"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}

//put this in onAppEnterBackground
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        NSLog(@"Sent to background by locking screen");
    } else if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"kDisplayStatusLocked"]) {
            NSLog(@"Sent to background by home button/switching to other app");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Sent to background by locking screen");
        }
    }

//put this in - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"kDisplayStatusLocked"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

```
CGFloat screenBrightness = [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness];

NSLog(@"Screen brightness: %f", screenBrightness);

UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];

if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

    NSLog(@"Sent to background by locking screen");

} else if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    if (screenBrightness > 0.0) {
        NSLog(@"Sent to background by home button/switching to other app");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Sent to background by locking screen");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you find a duplicate question, the correct action, once you have 15 rep, is to flag the post as a duplicate. Simply posting the same copy/paste answer around the site is not what we're about, and this creates noise.

Comment: @jmort253  Sorry, I don't know I should do like this. I am new user, but my answer is right I think.

Comment: not working for me. test it on iOS 7 (simulator and device). I don't think this is the right way of using [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness]. According to apple library documents, it's just a setting for screen brightness in this app, not necessary current screen brightness level.

Comment: @Perisheroy I am sure that will work on iOS7 device, I have test it on  my and my friend's iOS7 iPhone5. You can put code snippet in `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` at your appDelegate.m.  It is not work on iOS simulator, sorry I have not mention that before.

Comment: This is currently not working in the latest iOS 7 simulator. I can provide a video showing this if you'd like.

Comment: @JoseRafaelSantiagoJr. I have update my code. Please try this way again :).

Comment: @wqq Thanks for the update. It works beautifully! I put everything into a sample project on github for others to check out with credit given to you in the README: https://github.com/binarydev/ios-home-vs-lock-button

Comment: Will it be rejected by Apple? But you save my life. Thanks

Comment: @SeanChense It would not be rejected, I have submit my app many times.

Comment: Just tried it on iOS 9 and it worked WONDERFULLY. Thank you for such a great solution!

Comment: @KennyWyland did your app make it through review without problems?

Comment: It depends on apple I guess. If the tester is not having a great day, your app will be rejected.

Comment: mine got rejected

Answer (score 2):

This solution was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071009/can-we-detect-whether-a-user-left-through-the-home-button-or-lock-button-without?rq=1) and worked for me. It is a bit hacky but it makes it easier to be accepted on the appstore because it doesn't use *com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete* or *com.apple.springboard.lockstate*.

The following code goes into your AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if (DidUserPressLockButton()) {
        print("User pressed lock button")
    } else {
        print("user pressed home button")
    }
}

private func DidUserPressLockButton() -> Bool {
    let oldBrightness = UIScreen.main.brightness
    UIScreen.main.brightness = oldBrightness + (oldBrightness <= 0.01 ? (0.01) : (-0.01))
    return oldBrightness != UIScreen.main.brightness
}
```

The idea is to try changing the brightness of the screen after the application went to background and to check if this change was successful.

Disclaimer: it doesn't work on the simulator and you will have to test it on a real device.

Comment: the thing is when the app is already in the background then the user locks the screen it cant detect the action.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in Swift, you need to do some modification to make it work in Swift as follow

1.create a objectiveC file named LockNotifierCallback.m as follow:

```
static void displayStatusChanged(CFNotificationCenterRef center,
                                 void *observer,
                                 CFStringRef name,
                                 const void *object,
                                 CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {
    if ([(__bridge NSString *)name  isEqual: @"com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete"]) {
        NSLog(@"Screen Locked");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"kDisplayStatusLocked"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}

@implementation LockNotifierCallback

+ (void(*)(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo))notifierProc {
return displayStatusChanged;
}

@end
```

create a head as well:
    #import

```
@interface LockNotifierCallback : NSObject


+ (void(*)(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo))notifierProc;


@end
```

2.bridge this file to swift

3.add function to APPdelegate.swift:

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), nil, LockNotifierCallback.notifierProc(), "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete", nil, CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.DeliverImmediately)
```

PS:UIApplicationState doesn't work perfectly in here