# Detect screen lock or home button press on iOS9 and iOS10 in Swift 3

Tags: swift2, ios9, swift3, ios10, xcode8

The answer provided by Rean Wen in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595928/differentiate-between-screen-lock-and-home-button-press-on-ios7/39886725?noredirect=1#comment67060141_39886725) worked great in Swift 2.2, but now I upgraded to XCode 8.0 with Swift 3 and it does not work anymore.

I am getting the following error message:

```
.../project/AppDelegate.swift:41:108: Cannot convert value of type '(@convention(c) (CFNotificationCenter?, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, CFString?, UnsafeRawPointer?, CFDictionary?) -> Void)!' to expected argument type 'CFNotificationCallback!'
```

from this line:

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), nil, LockNotifierCallback.notifierProc(), "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete", nil, CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.DeliverImmediately)
```

inside the AppDelegate.swift file.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Since I just started learning Swift, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you.

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                    nil,
                                    { (_, observer, name, _, _) in

                                        print("received notification: \(name)")
        },
                                    "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" as CFString!,
                                    nil,
                                    .deliverImmediately)
```

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/swift-proper-use-of-cfnotificationcenteraddobserver-w-callback) for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem when I was developing a task management app recently. I try to solve this problem using Darwin Notification with CFNotificationCallback method.

Step 1:

Add the following code right under AppDelegate class declaration

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    let displayStatusChanged: CFNotificationCallback = { center, observer, name, object, info in
        let str = name!.rawValue as CFString
        if (str == "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" as CFString) {
            let isDisplayStatusLocked = UserDefaults.standard
            isDisplayStatusLocked.set(true, forKey: "isDisplayStatusLocked")
            isDisplayStatusLocked.synchronize()
        }
    }

    //other functions
}
```

Step 2:

Inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, add the following code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let isDisplayStatusLocked = UserDefaults.standard
    isDisplayStatusLocked.set(false, forKey: "isDisplayStatusLocked")
    isDisplayStatusLocked.synchronize()

    // Darwin Notification
    let cfstr = "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" as CFString
    let notificationCenter = CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter()
    let function = displayStatusChanged
    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(notificationCenter,
                                    nil,
                                    function,
                                    cfstr,
                                    nil,
                                    .deliverImmediately)

    return true
}
```

Step 3:

Inside `applicationDidEnterBackground`, add the following code:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {      
    let isDisplayStatusLocked = UserDefaults.standard
    if let lock = isDisplayStatusLocked.value(forKey: "isDisplayStatusLocked"){
        // user locked screen
        if(lock as! Bool){            
            // do anything you want here
            print("Lock button pressed.")
        }
        // user pressed home button
        else{            
            // do anything you want here
            print("Home button pressed.")
        }
    }
}
```

Step 4:

Inside `applicationWillEnterForeground`, add the following code:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("Back to foreground.")
    //restore lock screen setting
    let isDisplayStatusLocked = UserDefaults.standard
    isDisplayStatusLocked.set(false, forKey: "isDisplayStatusLocked")
    isDisplayStatusLocked.synchronize()  
}
```

You can take a look at the detailed approach here with a demo project: [swift-home-vs-lock-button](https://github.com/ImEric/swift-home-vs-lock-button)