# Swift, IOS, Detect power button pressed 3 times

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, appdelegate, applicationwillterminate

I want to do something like getting an event when a user has pressed the power button 3 times within 5 or 10 seconds.

Think of this like an SOS / emergency call. If the user pressed 3 times power button then I want to trigger a sound or alarm from within the app.

Can anyone suggest an alternative option if this is not possible. Can we get an event call multiple times when the method  `applicationWillResignActive` occurs?

Comment: Power button? Do you mean the [Side button](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203017)?

Comment: Yes, Side button to off/on device.

Comment: this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595928/differentiate-between-screen-lock-and-home-button-press-on-ios7/19771680#19771680

Comment: This post is for application is enter in the background using home screen or by the power button, But in my case app will enter background or it may already in the background when the user click power button 3-4 times,

Comment: Hi @AtulParmar, you found any solution to this ?