# Swift Xcode - how to differentiate between going to lock screen and going to home screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, locking, homescreen

When the app enters the background or WillResignActive, both functions are called in my SceneDelegate. How am I able to distinguish between when the user exits the app to the HomeScreen versus just locking their phone?

EDIT: I want to perform a different function in each scenario

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lock Unlock events iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706344/lock-unlock-events-iphone)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differentiate between screen lock and home button press on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595928/differentiate-between-screen-lock-and-home-button-press-on-ios7)