# How to recognise the way the app goes into background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, application-state

As far as I know by now there are two ways an app can move into background:

1) User pressed home button

2) The app has been left for a while without any action from user and device fell asleep

These two result in one - `applicationDidEnterBackground` method is called and application state becomes `UIApplicationState.Background`. So how do I know how exactly this happened? I know that it's possible because I have an app before my eyes which takes different action based on whether user pressed home button or not. Any ideas, guys?

Comment: Does the answer to question (or any of the questions linked there) help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595928/differentiate-between-screen-lock-and-home-button-press-on-ios7

Comment: @RüdigerHanke it seems to be helpful, i'll give it a try, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge (believe me, **I've tried**), there is no formal public API allowing you to do this. However, I found this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/binarydev/ios-home-vs-lock-button), the file you should specifically look at is the [app delegate implementation file](https://github.com/binarydev/ios-home-vs-lock-button/blob/master/Test/AppDelegate.m).

The repo says:

> This project describes how to detect when a user presses the home button to leave your application and when they press the lock button to put your app into the background.
>
> It utilizes CSNotificationCenter to detect Darwin notifications.

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889286/wqq) has answered two questions on Stack Overflow related to this, that the repo seems to be based on:

[Differentiate between screen lock and home button press on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595928/differentiate-between-screen-lock-and-home-button-press-on-ios7/19771680#19771680)

[How to differentiate between screen lock and home button press on iOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303703/how-to-differentiate-between-screen-lock-and-home-button-press-on-ios5/19771817#19771817)

I honestly have no clue if Apple would reject or accept this implementation. Do let me know if you end up using it somehow. I also believe this is iOS 7 and up.