# How to process tap on push notification banner at password-locked iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I process push notification at

```
application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
```

method in `AppDelegate.swift` module

When application is active I show my own banner in application window:

```
if application.applicationState == .active {
    // create banner
    banner.show()
}
```

When application is in background iOS show system banner and my application receive info when `application.applicationState` has `.background` value. If user tapped the banner application receive data again but `application.applicationState` is `.inactive` - in this case I opens entity item that info was received in notification.

But when the device is locked with a password (ie requires code or fingerprint):

- Application receive notification data only when user did tap the banner, not immediately as in just background mode (when device is not password-locked)
- After unlock application state is still `.background`

How can I differ background state after password-unlocking and background without locking?

I did try set flags by processing

```
applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
```

and

```
applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)
```

events but

```
application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
```

calls earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify whether the device is currently locked using the [`isProtectedDataAvailable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622925-isprotecteddataavailable) property of `UIApplication`

```
let isUnlocked = UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable
```

You can then use the combination of `isUnlocked` and `applicationState` to determine that you are in the background but that the device is locked and process accordingly.

Note that `isProtectedDataAvailable` will always return `true` if data protection isn't enabled on the device (e.g. no passcode is set).

Answer (score 0):

I think below thread will solve your problem:
[How to differentiate between screen lock and home button press on iOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303703/how-to-differentiate-between-screen-lock-and-home-button-press-on-ios5?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I haven't tried it but people says its working perfectly fine and even no issue with app approval process.

Comment: That thread is about leaving application. And my question is about entering app. Can you specify what answer can help me differ when device was password-locked before user entered app?