# Is it possible to distinguish between locking the device and sending an app to background for iOS 10 and swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I [found answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754317/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-between-locking-the-device-and-sending-an-app-to-b) for iOS 5 on my question, but what about iOS10? Can there is an implementation on Swift3? 
for iOS 5:

```
// Pressing the home button
Will resign active.
Did enter background.
// Tapping app icon on Springboard
Will enter foreground.
Did become active.

// Pressing the lock button
Will resign active.
Did enter background.
// Unlocking the device
Will enter foreground.
Did become active.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, when screen is locked the notification named com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete is called.

```
    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                    nil, { (_, observer, name, _, _) in
                                            print("Locked") 
                                         },
                                    "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" as CFString!,
                                    nil, deliverImmediately)
```

For detecting background/foreground mode you need to listen notifications.

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(handleForegroundMode), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(handleBackgroundMode), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
```

Comment: You can't use observe this notification any more, your app will get rejected due to Apple refined their app scanner tool.

Comment: Wow, that is quite new for me, thanks for info @evanchin

Answer (score 1):

Please don't observe "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" notification.
Apple refined their app scanner tool recently, the notification is part of private API, if you still observe this notification, your app will get rejected during submission.